# iOS, Universal links, Swift. continueUserActivity not calling

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I working on Universal links implementation for our iOS app.

Here is my small piece of AppDelegate:

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    DeepLinkHelpers.handleUniversalLink(url.absoluteString)
    return true
}

private func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    DeepLinkHelpers.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL?.absoluteString)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    signalRConnector.launch()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.processRestartSignalRNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "restartSignalR"), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,                            selector: #selector(AppDelegate.reachabilityChanged(_:)),
                                           name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,
                                           object: reachability)

    do {
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        Logger.save(text: "Unable to start notifier")
    }
    return true
}
```

I have processed all other steps for universal links integration:

1. Published apple-app-site-association file in our Web application
2. Switched on Associated domains feature on developers.apple.com
3. Specified associated domains in xcode
4. Checked Target Membership for entitlements file
5. Said xcode to wait until app will be started manually (instead of
   autostart)

I doing following to debug:

1. Connecting ipad
2. Starting project in xcode
3. In ipad opening Calendar and click on link contained in some event.
   Link has following format: app.domain.com/#/123456789
4. Ipad opens app but continueUserActivity not calling and i can't
   handle code from the url for navigate to exact state within an app.

According documentation continueUserActivity should be executed. It is not executing both when app is running in background and when app not running.

Thank you in advance! Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool
gives me error: Unable to parse that webpage URL. Try a different URL.

Comment: but this one says the all correct and all tests are green: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator

Comment: The Apple validator is _not_ a Universal Links validator and its results have no connection to whether Universal Links function or not. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169954/applinks-validator-domain-missing-from-entitlement/41173007#41173007) for more details on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is because you've marked the `continueUserActivity` function as `private`. I've never seen that, and in fact Swift 3 actually gives an error when I try. There don't appear to be any examples of code structured that way [on all of GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=private+func+application%28application%3A+UIApplication%2C+continueUserActivity&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

I'd suggest removing the `private` scope.

Comment: Thanks Alex!
I have changed my code to be: 
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        ...
        return true
    }

And it works now.

Comment: Thanks Alex, must have copied a bogus tutorial.

Answer (score 24):

As of iOS 12, Swift 4.2, and Xcode 10 Apple has again changed method signature (type of restorationHandler) to

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: 
NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
```

Comment: Note to self: treat warnings as errors before making a new build, Kristof.

Comment: @michal Ziobro this worked perfectly fine in my case where application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions was working.

Answer (score 4):

after ios 13 you should use ScenDelegate:

```
//when app is running

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity)

//when app is not running 
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)
```

Comment: You made my day fulfilled, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In 2019, this is what helped me (from this guide: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272 ):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print("Continue User Activity called: ")
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
        print(url.absoluteString)
        //handle url and open whatever page you want to open.
    }
    return true
}
```