# Appdelegate method of invoking Deeplink is not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, deeplink

I have implemented deeplinks in my application. The deeplinks are opening in Xcode 11.3 and iOS 11/12/13, but it is not opening in Xcode 10.2.1. When the `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])` method is invoked, then it redirects to the Appdelegate method in case of Xcode 11.3 and successfully the deeplink is opened, but in case of Xcode 10.2 this appDelegate method is not being invoked.:

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    }`

PS: I tried the option on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191472/ios-universal-links-swift-continueuseractivity-not-calling/52765819), but it didn't work for me.